# Qt: n param of QTranslator::translate() for non-singulars

Tags: qt, localization, internationalization

Qt [QTranslator::translate() documentation declares](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtranslator.html#translate-2) that

> If n is not -1, it is used to choose an appropriate form for the translation (e.g. "%n file found" vs. "%n files found").

It seems that there is no way to translate "%n men answered %n questions" as one string (i.e. I need to perform 2 QTranslator::translate() calls), or am I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd advise against attempting to use multiple numerus forms in a single translatable string.

- It's tricky, involving more than one call to `tr()`.
- It's complex. Some languages can have more than two numerus forms and the translation space grows in `O(n^m)` where `n` is the number of numerus forms in language and `m` is the number of number forms in your string to be translated string. Case in point: Arabic has six numerus forms and if you have two `%n`s in your string, you'll need 36 different translations.

So, better to structure your translatable strings so that max one `%n` is needed per string.

Comment: Formulae was obvious, yet thank you, and I accept it as the answer :)

Comment: While not the answer I hoped for, it makes a compelling argument ... I18n is hard, sometimes :-)